# Does one memory cell take part in different memories?

Tags: memory

Does one memory cell take part in different memories? For example, both in the visual memory of a bird and a monkey?

Answer (score 4):

According to engram theory: Yes.

However, you need more than one cell to encode a memory engram.
The idea is that the **combination** of cells encodes the memory, not the cells themselves.

I am most familiar with the hippocampus, in which cells participating in the encoding of "concepts" like Jennifer Aniston, Bill Clinton or the Sydney Opera House have been found in humans [Quiroga et al. (2008)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18262826)